# Firebase Cloud Firestore Query whereEqualTo for reference

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a query which only selects documents whose reference is equal to a given reference, using Java for Android development.  A document which it would match contains the reference for the path "/users/someUser".  I am creating the reference like so:

```
DocumentReference ref = mDatabase.document("users/someUser");
```

I have also tried:

```
DocumentReference ref = mDatabase.document("/users/someUser");
```

Then the query:

```
Query query = mDatabase.collection("myCollection").whereEqualTo("refField", ref).limit(10);
```

However, when I run the query and check the `task.isSuccessful()` in the onComplete method, it's not passing, i.e. it didn't work, whereas when I remove the `.whereEqualTo()`, it passes and the task's result isn't empty.  How can I properly use `.whereEqualTo()` to check for all documents containing a specific reference?

An example of a document that should match my query would be:

`/myCollection/GDpojS5koac2C7YlIqxS` which contains the field:
`refField: /users/someUser`  (value of type reference)

And an example of a document that should not match my query would be:

`/myCollection/J5ZcVAMYU1nI5XZmh6Bv` which contains the field:
`refField: /users/wrongUser`  (value of type reference)

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Android with Java, I'll clarify in my question - thanks for catching that.

Comment: Please edit the question to show, as an example, what documents you are searching against, and the documents that you expect to match from your query.

Comment: @DougStevenson Edited my question with examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add a get() method to run the query and add an onCompletionListener.

Something like this should work:

```
mDatabase.collection("myCollection")
  .whereEqualTo("refField", ref)
  .limit(10)
  .get()
  .addOnCompleteListener({task ->
                         if(task.isSuccessful){
                            val result = task.result                 
                        })
```

*The above example is in kotlin, but i guess in java it is something similar*

Answer (score -2):

You need not to worry about the documents, if you create a query based on your fields then all the documents will be returned in the "QuerySnapshot" object, 
for eg,

```
CollectionReference collectionReference = db.collection(FIRESTORE_USERS);
                DocumentReference documentReference = collectionReference.document(userID);
                CollectionReference notificationCollection = documentReference.collection(FIRESTORE_NOTIFICATIONS);

    notificationCollection.whereEqualTo(USER_TYPE, userType)
                        .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo(SEND_AT, calendar.getTime())
                        .get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots) {
                        List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshotsList = documentSnapshots.getDocuments();
                        ArrayList<NotificationCollections> notificationCollectionsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (DocumentSnapshot snapshot : snapshotsList) {
                       // each document having that particular field based on query
    }
    }});
```

in the above example I am fetching all those documents which match a particular user id and also having time greater than or equal to supplied time (time will not be used in your case)

I hope this helps...

Happy coding :)